# Editing Lists In Place

Tags: python, list, math

Trying to find the sine of angles in a list. The function should not return anything and must not make a new list.

Not sure how to go about doing this, but this is what I have tried so far:

```
for item in range(len(angles)):
        a2 = math.sin(math.radians(item)) 
        angles[0:(len(angles)].append(a2)
```

Comment: You can use list comprehension: `angles = [sin(i) for i in angles]`

Comment: Hello Bira, Are you getting the list of angles and in the same list you must change values with their sin values? By overwriting each position?

Comment: @BrandonMolyneaux, OP stated that "must not make a new list."

Comment: Yes! Thats what I need to do! @ Filip Matyja

Answer (score 2):

If you *must* do this as an in-place substitution:

```
for i, angle in enumerate(angles):
    a2 = math.sin(math.radians(angle))
    angles[i] = a2
```

If you don't mind instantiating another list, and your only requirement is that the initial `angles` list is mutated:

```
angles[:] = [math.sin(math.radians(angle)) for angle in angles]
```

Comment: note that `angle` here is not the same as `item` in your code -- it is the angle at each index of `angles` (which seems to be what you wanted in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the job. If something is unclear in the code, just give me a shout.

```
import math

angles = [10,20,30,40,50,60]

for value in angles:
    index = angles.index(value)
    angles[index] = math.sin(math.radians(value))

print(angles)
```

Comment: This won't work if one of the later angles is equal to the sin of one of the earlier angles.

Comment: Can you please provide the example of such list, that this program will be no working on?

Comment: `angles = [50, 0.766044443118978]`. Should result in `[0.766044443118978, 0.013369599422835134]`, but actually changes the first value twice.

Comment: Plus all those calls to `angles.index` is really painful. Generate a list of 10,000+ angles and that gets *really* expensive.